# Bind service with multiple activity

Tags: java, android, android-service

I want to bind service with multiple activities so I've written an Application class to managed this goal:

```
public class BluetoothController extends Application {
    private static BluetoothController mInstance;
    private ClientBluetoothService mService;
    protected boolean mBound = false;

    public static synchronized BluetoothController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void startService(){
        //start your service
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClientBluetoothService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
    public void stopService(){
        //stop service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    public ClientBluetoothService getService(){
        return  mService;
    }

    public boolean isBound() {
        return mBound;
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {

            ClientBluetoothService.LocalBinder binder = (ClientBluetoothService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getSerivce();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

And to access this class in Activity I'm using for example:

```
BluetoothController.getInstance().startService();
```

But I have an error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.gmail.krakow.michalt.myecg.BluetoothController.startService()' on a null object reference.
How can it be solved?

Comment: In addition-  there's no need to do this at all.  If you want to bind multiple activities to a service, just call bindService in each.  Or put it into a common base class of your Activity.  It makes no sense to put it into Application

Comment: How are you intending on using `BluetoothController `, calling `isBound()` followed by `getService()`, then manually binding with an intent anyway?

Comment: It was not the best idea. If followed the instructions given by @GabeSechan  and it works well.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static synchronized BluetoothController getInstance() {
    return mInstance = new BluetoothController();
}
```

Comment: Obviosuly you should never call `new operator` with class like `Application`, `Service`, `Activity` by yourself